# Angular data service properties are undefined

Tags: angular, service

I'm using an Angular service to make requests with an SDK and another to manage wallet data. However, using the wallet-service within the SDK-service shows that the service does not exists.

Logging it within the SDK-service constructor shows `{}`

sdk-service

```
export class SdkService {
  constructor(private walletService: WalletService) {
    console.log(this.walletService); // {}
    ...
```

Since both services are singletons and provided `forRoot` what could be missing that the service is not injected and available?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense... `WalletService.wallets$` was supposed to be initialized, indeed. Can you provide a stackblitz reproducing this issue?

Comment: Thank you for responding, just pasted my setup into a SB and it works... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14-template-fk4scq?file=src/app/service-two.service.ts not sure what could be different in my basic application.

Comment: Do you have: `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` in `WalletService`?

Comment: Yes, both services are singletons. 
I've updated the question. The service is not even available within the SDK service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `services` are injectable classes in Angular. They are a manifestation of the Singelton pattern in the design patterns terminology. Meaning you will have one single instance of the class/object initialized in the application lifecycle. When you have a cyclic injection issue the framework will throw a runtime error.

Back to your issue practically, you are using `BehaviourSubject` from RxJs. BehaviourSubject expects a default value. If you do not supply a default value it will send the current value as `undefined`. Thus, your problem in question. If you do not care about default value and only about latest emitted value then you just need to use `Subject` instead of `BehaviourSubject`.

```
private _wallets$: Subject<IWallet[]> = new Subject<IWallet[]>();
```

The other option to guard against the value of the stream being accessed before it gets initialized is to add a conditional statement before subscribing

Edit:
You updated the OP, so please provide the error you are getting or the structure of your modules

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've realized that the problem is deeper than the observable. The service is not available within the SDK service which makes no sense. It is not provided anywhere else, only `forRoot`.

Comment: Do you use  ModuleWithProviders in a custom servicesModule? can you provide the code for it?

Comment: I do not. However I just realized that I was including walletService into SDK-service and vice-versus. Now I have wallet-service available in the SDK service.

Comment: If you use the sdkService within another module with .forRoot() that implies you have a custom module for services in which you have a method called forRoot() with an Object wrapper named ModuleWithProviders that allows you list all your services in this module and then just import this servicesModule in your consumer modules without the need to supply the services individually, this is so the framework will instantiate the services as singeltons through this ModuleWithProviders wrapper.

Comment: @BenRacicot, okay cool. If things are working that's nice. Otherwise a stackblitz will help identifying your problem better.

Comment: I know exactly what you are describing and I have not implemented that. I'm fully relying on the `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`. These services are not provided or included within any module in my entire app.